# Unable to call public static method in other unity script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a two an "enemy" sprite that when the "player" sprite touches, should cause damage.

The PlayerStatus script just holds information about the players health.
When the EnemyAIController OnTriggerEnter2D method is fired, I wanted to call a method in the PlayerStatus script that would reduce the health by x amount.

I made the **TakeDamage** method accessor public with a static modifier. So I could call `PlayerStatus.TakeDamage(float x)`, but that doesn't work.

I get the error: ***An object reference is required to access non-static member `PlayerStatus.TakeDamage(float)'***

I didn't want to use `findObjectByTag` because I have read that is slow and a lazy way of doing it.

***Am I missing something?***

**PlayerStatus Script:**

```
public class PlayerStatus : MonoBehaviour {

    public float health = 3.0f;

    public static void TakeDamage(float damage){
        health -= damage;

    }

}
```

**EnemyAIController Script:**

```
public class EnemyAIController : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {

            Debug.Log("Reduce Player Health"); 
            PlayerStatus.TakeDamage (1.0f);

    }

}
```

Comment: Jaka has explained your problem.  But remember -- it is an awfully good idea to have STATIC ***CLASSES*** and only write static calls inside that static class.  Something to consider.

Comment: **WHAT YOU ARE DOING IS EXTREMELY DANGEROUS**  Don't forget PlayerStatus is a MonoBehavior.  ***WHAT IS IT ATTACHED TO?**  What happens if you have more than one PlayerStatus script in your game?

Comment: Yikes. Anywhere specific I can read up on this?

Comment: Thanks for the ominous warning and then leaving without further explanation @JoeBlow

Comment: i already typed "What happens if you have more than one PlayerStatus script in your game?"  it's almost meaningless, and at any rate poorly defined, to use static methods in an ECS milieu.  for something like "health" and "scoring" (basically "globals") in a game engine, just use static class (with of course static methods)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is within class `PlayerStatus`. Inside static method `TakeDamage` you are accessing non-static variable `health` which of course can not be done.

```
public static float health = 3.0f; // inside class PlayerStatus
```

Should help you resolve the error.

Otherwise, I'd recommend that you create a non static method `TakeDamage`, use `findObjectByTag`, and you can do it once in constructor (to avoid performance penalty). Simply save the result in class property, where you access it inside `OnTriggerEnter2D:

(more of a pseudo code)

```
public class EnemyAIController : MonoBehaviour {

    private PlayerStatus _player;

    public EnemyAIController() {
        // call base() if neccessery
        _player = findObjectByTag("your player");
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {

            Debug.Log("Reduce Player Health"); 
            this._player.TakeDamage (1.0f);

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please double check that you have STATIC keyword in public static float health = 3.0f; (might have forgotten to add it in first revision of my answer), otherwise I'm left out of ideas. Will think some more.

Comment: This is the answer to this question. So I marked it as such. Some people seem to think this is an improper way of doing this.... Your mileage may vary.

Comment: If it fits your code and pattern, it's the proper way of doing it :). Otherwise I generally like to avoid static methods especially in cases like this, singleton might be more appropriate maybe.

Comment: there are **no** singletons in Unity - MonoBehaviors can't really be a singleton, they are only meaningful as a Component "attached" to a `GameObject`.  unity is "ECS" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system, a game engine (frame-based and scene-based) is not ordinary OO

Comment: "If it fits your code and pattern, it's the proper way of doing it" nah, not in ECS.  consider, there's a particular `GameObject` somewhere with a particular `PlayerStatus` attached to it.  OK, so in Unity you have a component attached to a game object - like everything else.  Say you want to access that from some other script. You know how to do it - drag an inspector variable or "Find" it at Awake time.  totally no big deal, and just how unity works.  If you think about it **all you are trying to do** is circumvent that ordinary process to make it syntactically easier. it's a non-starter